# Maybe monad inside stack of transformers

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following code:

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

type T = StateT Int IO Int

someMaybe = Just 3

f :: T
f = do
    x <- get
    val <- lift $ do
        val <- someMaybe
        -- more code in Maybe monad
        -- return 4
    return 3
```

When I use `do` notation inside to work in `Maybe` monad it fails. From the error it gives it looks like type signature for this `do` doesn't match. However I have no idea how to fix it. I tried some `lift` combinations, but none of them worked and I don't want to guess anymore.

Comment: Do you want the code in the inner `do` to run only in the `Maybe` monad, or does it need access to the `StateT Int` and `IO` too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `Maybe` is not part of your transformer stack. If your transformer only knows about `StateT Int` and `IO`, it does not know anything about how  to lift `Maybe`.

You can fix this by changing your type `T` to something like:

```
type T = StateT Int (MaybeT IO) Int
```

(You'll need to import `Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe`.)

You will also need to change your inner `do` to work with `MaybeT` rather than `Maybe`. This means wrapping raw `Maybe a` values with `MaybeT . return`:

```
f :: T
f = do
    x <- get
    val <- lift $ do
        val <- MaybeT $ return someMaybe
        -- more code in Maybe monad
        return 4
    return 3
```

This is a little awkward, so you probably want to write a function like `liftMaybe`:

```
liftMaybe = MaybeT . return
```

If you used `lift` to lift `IO a` values in other parts of your code, this will now break because you have three levels in your transformer stack now. You will get an error that looks like this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `MaybeT IO t0'
            with actual type `IO String'
```

To fix this, you should use `liftIO` for all your raw `IO a` values. This uses a typeclass to life `IO` actions through any number of transformer layers.

In response to your comment: if you only have a bit of code depending on `Maybe`, it would be easier just to put the result of the `do` notation into a variable and match against that:

```
let maybeVal = do val <- someMaybe
                  -- more Maybe code
                  return 4
case maybeVal of
  Just res -> ...
  Nothing  -> ...
```

This means that the `Maybe` code will not be able to do an IO. You can also naturally use a function like `fromMaybe` instead of `case`.

Comment: I have a bunch of functions which operate in this monad, but in only one of them I have to unpack some values from `Maybe` and using `do` notation would allow me to get rid of nested `case` expresion. Is defining type the only way to do this?

Comment: It's of course also possible to use `runMaybeT` for the block that uses the `MaybeT` transformer.

Comment: @Adrian: You can just extract the `do` notation into its own function and then have a single case expression matching against that. In fact, that's probably the best approach; however, you should play around with my version a bit to understand monad transformers more.

Comment: And thus the case for using `mtl`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run the code in the inner `do` purely in the `Maybe` monad, you will not have access to the `StateT Int` or `IO` monads (which might be a good thing).  Doing so will return a `Maybe` value, which you will have to scrutinize:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

type T = StateT Int IO Int

someMaybe = Just 3

f :: T
f = do
    x <- get
    -- no need to use bind
    let mval = do
        -- this code is purely in the Maybe monad
        val <- someMaybe
        -- more code in Maybe monad
        return 4
    -- scrutinize the resulting Maybe value now we are back in the StateT monad
    case mval of
        Just val -> liftIO . putStrLn $ "I got " ++ show val
        Nothing -> liftIO . putStrLn $ "I got a rock"
    return 3
```